# Edit table tags using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working with software to create a site, I am unable to directly edit the HTML. This is a table where information is pulled in as teams register/receive donations. I would like to use tablesorter.js to sort the information by the donation amount but this requires using the  tags for the header, the table that is created by the software does not use this tag, see below:

```
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#003399" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0">
            <tbody><tr><td>
                <table width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
                    <tbody><tr bgcolor="#003399">

                        <td colspan="4" class="white"><b>Click on the Group for more information: </b></td>

                    </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white"><td align="center" colspan="4"><img src="#">&nbsp;Indicates Group is accepting new members.</td></tr>

                    <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><b>Group Name</b></td>
                        <td><b>Group Captain</b></td>

                        <td><b>Donation Total</b></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><td></td><td><a href="#">test1</a></td><td>test test</td><td>$20.00</td></tr><tr bgcolor="#eeeeee"><td></td><td><a href="#">test2</a></td><td>test test</td><td>$50.00</td></tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><td align="center" colspan="4"><img src="#">&nbsp;Indicates Group is accepting new members from the public.</td></tr>                 

                </tbody></table>
            </td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

See JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/kt8jzg9e/1/

What I need to do: starting with "Group Name" and anything after, this information needs to go into it's own table utilizing  and  tags, after the  the rest of the table goes into  please see below:

```
<table><thead><th>Group Name</th><th>Group Captain</th><th>Donation Total</th></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</test2> . . . </tbody></table>
```

Any help would be greatly apprecieated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: description of objective is far from being concise.

Comment: Not sure how else to explain it, I need to wrap the row that contains Group Name, Group Captain, and Donation Total with <thead>. I then need to wrap each of those headings (Group Name...etc) with <th> instead of <td>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on objective outlined in comments you can do something like this:

```
var $existTable= $('table td table');

var $newTable = $('<table id="newTable"><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');
$newTable.find('thead').append($existTable.find('tr').eq(2));
$newTable.find('tbody').append($existTable.find('tr:gt(1)'));
$existTable.parent().append( $newTable );


$newTable.tablesorter();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kt8jzg9e/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! One more question, is it possible to sort descending by default instead and disable the option to click the column to sort? I would like the table to always display in descending order based on the donation total.

Comment: I'm not sure but I thinks so. Will need to read API docs. I haven't followed tablesorter plugin for a long time

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to sort descending but was not able to set this as the default when the page loads. Viewers still have to click first. Any way around this?

Comment: can always trigger a click using jQuery `click()`